# What species is this bird?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, ornithology

This bird is a frequent "visitor" at a lake south west of Berlin, GERMANY.
[image]

For more pictures here's a link:
https://goo.gl/photos/ADVSZwbDQUpbomCBA

Answer (score 7):

It's a BLACK KITE (*Milvus migrans*). I bet you took the pics this summer because the great majority of the population is in Africa at the moment.

It is a black kite because:

- rather uniform dark brown color
- squared tail (it form a shallow v during gliding)
- uniform underwing color and lighter head is a shared with marsh harrier but the absence of darker patch around the eye, the dark shoulder and 6 digitated primaries assure us is a black kite.

Here is a picture for reference:
[image: Milvus migrans]